# Drag Back to Previous View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

When I push a new view controller in my app, I can pan from the very leftmost side of the screen and drag the view off (to the right) so that I'm back at the parent view controller.  The motion follows my finger; I can drag it halfway and then back to the left if I want.  This is built in.

I'm wanting to extend this functionality to the entire view.  I want to be able to drag right from the center of the view and have it 'segue' back to the previous view controller, but not go all the way until my finger is released.  It doesn't seem like a swipe gesture recognizer is what I want because that will segue all in one action.  I have done some searching but I don't think I should have to implement a page view controller or a scroll view since similar functionality already exists.

What can I do to either modify the existing drag functionality or add a new gesture recognizer to accomplish this?